# How to declare emoji character variable and print it in Swift?

Tags: swift

I don't know how to declare a emoji character as a variable and assign some value to it and print it. When I create Emoji variable the compiler shows an error error.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Edit -> Emoji & Symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
 var  = "hello"
 println()
```

Answer (score 6):

Choose an emoji by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>

```
var  = "whatsup"
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Introduction to Swift from WWDC 2014, the syntax for declaring an emoji as a variable name is:

```
var  = "cat"
```